# Почему в названии "Серебряный Бор" второе слово пишется с заглавной?

Tags: орфография

Почему в собственном имени "Серебряный Бор" оба слова пишутся с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 5):

**Серебряный Бор** — памятник природы регионального значения, особо охраняемая природная территория города Москвы.

Для памятника природы слово "Бор" – условное название (это же природная зона, а не лес), а все условные названия пишутся с прописной буквы.

Аналогично: Кузнецкий Мост, где Мост – тоже условное название (это же улица, а не настоящий мост).

Answer (score 2):

Вот [здесь](https://aprikablog.ru/2019/12/toponimy-propisnaya-ili-strochnaya/) тоже пишут про Кузнецкий Мост:

> Правило здесь действует следующее. В составных названиях географических объектов все слова пишутся с прописной, если они употреблены не в своем обычном значении.
>
> Что значит «не в своем обычном значении»?
>
> Возьмём упомянутый выше Кузнецкий Мост. Был раньше такой мост через
> реку Неглинку, воистину. Но в данном случае речь идет о названии
> улицы, так что слово мост в этом названии употреблено не в изначальном
> смысле. По той же причине пишем: Охотный Ряд, Большая Речка (название
> поселка, а не реки), Пушкинские Горы (тоже поселок, а не горы),
> Никитские Ворота (это не ворота, а площадь в Москве), Огненная Земля
> (архипелаг), Сосновый Бор (город в Ленинградской области), Царское
> Село (потому что не село).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]